# stringbuffer toString does not match with same static string

Tags: php, android, http-post, httpresponse, stringbuffer

I am in middle of an issue where I am getting a string "INSERTED SUCCESSFULLY" as the response from my httprequest, my aim was to match it with a local string (same as above) however when I try to match them they dont match hence does not enter into my condition.

```
UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters);
request.setEntity(entity);             
HttpResponse response= httpClient.execute(request);
bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
String line = "";
String LineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
stringBuffer.append(line + LineSeparator); 
}
bufferedReader.close();
String q = "INSERTED SUCCESSFULLY";
StringBuffer got = new StringBuffer(q);
Log.d("Response", stringBuffer.toString());//MY logcat shows "INSERTED SUCCESSFULLY"
if(stringBuffer.equals(got))
   {
               // Does not enter here
       Log.d("xyz", "Getting Response" + stringBuffer.toString());
      //some TASK
   }
```

That does anything to do with encoding.
N.B:- my php code just echo "INSERTED SUCCESSFULLY".

I tried doing the following code as well with no success

```
if(stringBuffer.toString().equals("INSERTED SUCCESSFULLY")
```

Comment: problem is `LineSeparator` because you are adding new line in first StringBuffer but not in second so always getting `FALSE`. either add line separator in second string or call `trim()` on both Strings to compare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(stringBuffer.toString().trim().equals("INSERTED SUCCESSFULLY")
```

try with this may be there were some starting or ending space